# Insert multiple rows into mysql (items separated by comma)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small problem :) I was searching the web but didn't find any solutions.

I have a value like this (got it from $_GET[])

tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4

and all I want to do is insert it into MySql (via PHP) like this:

```
+---------+-------------+
|      id |         tag |
+---------+-------------+
|      33 |        tag1 |
|      33 |        tag2 |
|      33 |        tag3 |
|      33 |        tag4 |
+---------+-------------+
```

I found many articles about this on Stack Overflow but the biggest problem here is that I don't know how many values I'm gonna get each time (I did not find that answer).

I will appreciate any help I get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi greetings from UK :)
Can't you just loop through the querystring fields and add one row to the database at a time?

e.g.

```
<?php

$id = 33;
$value_list = 'tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4';
$values = explode(',', $value_list);
foreach ($values as $value)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES ($id, '$value');";
    //.. execute SQL now
    echo '<p>' . $sql . '</p>';
}

?>
```

I uploaded this to http://cyba.co/test.php so you can see the output.

Comment: Ah - you mean "tag1, tag2, tag3" is a continuous string? You could split these into an array using "expode"

Comment: I used explode and with this code I get only 0, 1, 2, 3 into Mysql

Comment: Now I get only the second tag into mysql.

Comment: Ok I added an "echo" and uploaded the script to the URL shown - you can see the results show that it *should* work. If not, can you post your updated code so we can see where a problem could be? :)

Comment: Now it works like a charm. I don't know what was wrong before, all I know is that next time I'm in UK I should buy you a beer or two :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `INSERT INTO` with multiple values:

```
INSERT INTO table (tag) VALUES ('tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3');
```

Make sure, you properly escape your input (if user suplied) to prevent SQL injection. You can use `mysql_escape_string()` for this.

**Edit:** To get these values, you can do:

```
$values = explode(",", $_GET['your_param']);
foreach($values as $idx => $val) {
  $values[$idx] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($val));
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (tag) VALUES (".implode(",", $values).");");
```

Comment: but how you are going to get `'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'` from `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4`???

Comment: Added another revision, so hopefully  now everything is clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()` function to split the string

```
$tag  = "tag1, tag2, tag3";
$pieces = explode(", ", $tag);
```

SQL query would be

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ($pieces[0],$pieces[1],$pieces[2]);
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Since Matic said he did not know how many tags there would be at any given time, Matic would need to loop through the array you created.

Comment: @user984869 : agreed... then there is problem what if tag are less?? is he going to have NULL there? we will need table structure then... what are your thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

**This will work out according to your result**

```
$tagData = array();
$tagList  = explode(",","tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4");
foreach ($tagList as $key=>$value) {
    $tagData[] = '("' . $key . '", "' . $tagList[$key] . '")';
 }
$query = 'INSERT INTO tags (id,tag) VALUES' . implode(',', $tagData);
echo $query;die;
mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your comma-delimited tags into an array, then loop through the array to do your inserts.

```
$data_array=explode(",",$tag); // converts tags to an array based on the comma

// loop through each item in the array
foreach($data_array as $one_tag){

// Get rid of the space you have in your tag string
$one_tag=trim($one_tag);

// Do whatever sanitization you need to do to your data, for example...
$one_tag=mysql_real_escape_string($one_tag);

// Insert into the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table SET tag='$one_tag'");

}
```

You can make this more efficient using Prepared Statements, but it kept this example simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=33;

$tag=$_GET['tag'];
$tag_Split= explode(",", $tag);

$cnt=count($tag_Split);

for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++)
{
mysql_query("insert into tag_table(id,tag) 
values ($id, $tag_Split[$i])");
}
```

Comment: check the place where you get the tags do not add comma and space after each entry only add a comma.

Comment: I removed space after comma and the same thing happens

Comment: try var_dump($tagStr) if it is like "tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4" then explode should work.

Comment: Still no success, anything I try I get all the same values or just one.

Comment: what is you $tag string output

Answer (score -1):

Try this for size: (combining ideas from a number of people who almost got it right).

```
$values =  array(
                    33=>'tag1'),
                    33=>'tag2'),
                    33=>'tag3'),
                );

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, value) VALUES ";
$count=0;
foreach ($values as $id=> $value)
{
    if ($count++ > 0)
        $sql .= ',';
    $sql .= "($id, '$value')";
}
$query = mysql_query($sql, $db);
```