# Insert multiple check box values into multiple rows in one table?

Tags: foreach, explode, implode, mysql-insert-id

I have multiple check box with the same input name like this

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop1">pop1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop2">pop2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop3">pop3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop4">pop4 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop5">pop5<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop6">pop6 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop7">pop7<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop8">pop8 <br>
```

The database table contains two columns (`ID` and `POPNAME`).

I need every pop checked to inserted into database in separate row but with the same ID so this is my PHP:

```php
$pop = implode(',', $_POST['pop']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pops (id, popname) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$pop')");
```

But this not working. I tried to stick to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192740/insert-multiple-rows-into-mysql-items-separated-by-comma) make explode then use for each but also not working. This is the foreach code:

```php
$pop = implode(',', $_POST['pop']);
$pops = explode(',', $pop);
foreach ($pops as $pop )
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO pops (id, popname) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$pop')");
}
```

Am I missing something!

Comment: For who -1 please tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved.

Problem is `$pop` defined twice one as a var another one in `foreach`

So after rename the first var every thing ok

```
$popimp = implode(',', $_POST['pop']);
$pops = explode(',', $pop);
foreach ($pops as $pop )
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pops (id, popname) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$pop')");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PDO php:**
 Database connection code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'yourDB';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$dbhost};dbname={$dbname}",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

and php code:

```
 $pop= implode(', ', $_POST['pop']);
 $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO popTable (pop) VALUES (?)");
 $statement->execute(array($pop));
 $success_message = "Order's has been inserted successfully.";
```

**html:**

```
<form action="pop_form">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop1">pop1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop2">pop2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop3">pop3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop4">pop4 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop5">pop5<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop6">pop6 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop7">pop7<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="pop[]" value="pop8">pop8 <br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```